# Можно ли сделать собственные атрибуты у объектов UserControl WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Например, есть UserControl, а в нём три TextBlock. Можно ли на каждый TextBlock у UserControl добавить собственные атрибуты?

Ну, например:

```
<local:UserControl1 Txt1="Первый" Txt2="Второй" Txt3="Третий"/>
```

Comment: UserControl вы пишете? Если да, то вы можете делать с ним все, что угодно.

Comment: [Можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895926/12888024), `DependencyProperty` называется.